# Laravel - User > Roles > Permissions within a Company

Tags: laravel

I am trying to describe a relationship between a User and a Company. More specific I want the following:

- A User has one or Many Roles within a Company.
- A Role has one or Many Permissions.

```html
- users     (id, name, surname, email, ...)
- permissions       (id, name, label, ...)
- roles             (id, name, label,...)
- companies     (id, name, address, ...)
- permission_role   (permission_id, role_id)
- user_role         (user_id, role_id)
- company_user  (company_id, user_id)
```

Anyone could help me out?

ER Diagram: https://prnt.sc/q4l614

Comment: use "spatie/laravel-permission" package for permission may solve your problem.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use an ACL package. There are many packages availables: Spatie, Entrust, Laratrust etc. It would be best you check the docs of any to get started!

Comment: @sachinkumar I appriciate the reply, but I am looking for the solution for my specific problema and not using other packages. Feel free to give reply If you can help !

Comment: @TomasC.Lopes. you want to describe relationship between User and Role, Role and Permission. am i correct ?

Comment: Well I know you don't want to use any package. But when you use this package in any demo project you will get an idea how the database should look like to solve the permission and roles issues

Comment: @sachinkumar that packages doesn't support the permissions I need, I already checked.

Comment: This package support permission for the user ans their role. And as per you said may we can create has many through relationships for companies users and their permissions

Comment: I have attacked the UML diagram, feel free to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pivot_table` name will be like `user_role_company`. Pivot table structure will be like

> **role_user** Table
>   
>   `+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+
>   | id      |user_id    | role_id  | company_id  |
>   +---------+-----------+----------+-------------+
>   |   1     |    1      |   2      |    3        |
>   +---------+-----------+----------+-------------+`

- One User has one or many company id,
- One User has also one or many role id,
- One Role has belongs to many user
- One Role has belongs to many company.
- One Company has belongs to many user.
- One Company has belongs to many role.

All of this scenario. you can implements scenario by this -

In `User` Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   public function roles()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
   }
   public function companyies()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
   }
}
```

In `Role` Model -

```
class Role extends Model
{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }

  public function companies()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
  }
}
```

In `Company` Model -

```
class Company extends Model
{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }

  public function roles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
  }
}
```

Same as for `Role` and `Permission`.

You can check the relationship using Laravel `tinker`.

> I Hope it will work for you.

you can read more details from this link : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I appreciate the reply! Perhaps I failed to explain myself. My goal here is to handle One or Many Companies. 

A user can belong to One or Many Companies, and within that company he can have one role (to simplify) which has one or many permissions.

Comment: @TomasC.Lopes, you can use `belongsToMany()` relations for both `One` or `Many`.

Comment: My problem is how to model the relationship between User > Company > Role > Permission, which tables I need, etc... I'm stuck !

Comment: can you please explain your scenario graphically ?  it will better for me. thank you

Comment: @Gabrielle-MI hope this illustrate my goal: https://prnt.sc/q4l614

Comment: @TomasC.Lopes I updated my answer. please check, I think it will help for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a star!